# Echo highest value from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to get number from texts exist in IDs then select the highest of them and echo it in an ID HTML field, but the value will be echoed depends on the IDs' values: the code explains it more.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function status() {
        var d = document.getElementById('mom').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var h = document.getElementById('dad').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var u = document.getElementById('sister').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var n = document.getElementById('brother').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var s = document.getElementById('none').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];

        var res = [d, h, u, n, s];
        var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, res);

        switch (largest) {
            case 0: result = '<div>Im A</div>'; break;
            case 1: result = '<div>Im B</div>'; break;
            case 2: result = '<div>Im C</div>'; break;
            case 3: result = '<div>Im D</div>'; break;
            case 4: result = '<div>Im E</div>'; break;
        }

        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: the code doesnt return the value i need, it returns nothing

Comment: `console.log` out `res`, make sure they're what you're expecting

Comment: if i remove the switch code and change the `innerHTML = largest ; ` it works and return the value. So i believe something wrong with the switch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you want to retrieve index of array which has highest value and apply switch over the index.

```
var res = [d, h, u, n, s];
//var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, res);
var maxValueIndex = res.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMax] ? i : iMax, 0);

switch (maxValueIndex) {
    case 0: result = '<div>Im A</div>'; break;
    case 1: result = '<div>Im B</div>'; break;
    case 2: result = '<div>Im C</div>'; break;
    case 3: result = '<div>Im D</div>'; break;
    case 4: result = '<div>Im E</div>'; break;
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
```